# Minimum Requirements to run React-Native on Mac OS

Tags: windows, macos, react-native, virtual-machine

I am having windows right now, and planning to install virtual box to develop android/ios apps on React-Native.
And, definitely I need android studio and xcode both.
So would like to know the minimum hardware requirements (If I need to buy a new one or my current one works) and memory to be allotted to VM to run MacOS smoothly.

Currently I have a windows PC, with the following requirements -
Windows 10, i5 processor, 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD, 64 bit OS.

Any help would be appreciated.
And also, if I do so, would it run properly without any lag or hang?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to get at least 8GB, preferably 16GB or higher RAM. The build process will require quite a bit of RAM usage. Unless you have enough RAM you will lose lots of time, especially if you're planning to run both simulators. CPU could be better, more core/threads the better but i5 should be okay.

Other than the 4GB ram, others look fine for a minimum hardware requirement. But you definitely need more than 4 GB.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy! I will definitely make sure for more than 4 GB and may get higher processor as well.

Comment: do we need GPU stronger for react native?